# Foreign Key is null when insert using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql

I've created a insert stored procedure with two tables like in the exapmle:

Table NameAge

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assignment3_NameAge]
(
userID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Age int NOT NULL
)
```

Table Hobbies

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assignment3_Hobbies]
(
hobbiesID int Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
userID int Foreign Key references Assignment3_NameAge(userID),
hobbies varchar(255) NOT NULL,
)
```

Insert Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].p_Assignment3Join_ins
        @Name             nvarchar(100),
        @Age              int,
        @Hobbies          nvarchar(100)                   
AS
INSERT INTO [TABLE].[dbo].[Assignment3_NameAge]
           ([Name]
           ,[Age])
VALUES (@Name,@Age)

INSERT INTO [TABLE].[dbo].[Assignment3_Hobbies]
           ([Hobbies])
VALUES (@Hobbies)
```

The problem is that when i run the stored procedure the table Hobbies has a null value for userid(the foreign key)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What type of DB are you using (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the key of the `Assignment3_NameAge` value you want to insert into `Assignment3_Hobbies`.

If you want the last inserted you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from SQL Server(if you're using SQL Server) or equivalent. It will give you the last inserted value from `Assignment3_NameAge`

Comment: Never use @@identity for this. Use scope_identity() or the output clause instead. @@identity will return the incorrect value once someone adds a trigger to the table that also has an identity and cause data integrity issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is SQL Server based on the IDENTITY column.  Correct?

The first insert creates a user, but there is no user ID being set on the insert of the hobby.  You need to capture the identity value from the first insert to be used in the second insert.  Have you gon over the system functions available?

Comment: I was leading towards the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function, since this appeared to be a homework assignment I was trying to lead the poster to the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You're not supplying a value for it, SQL won't automagically fill the value in for you even though you've created a Foreign Key relationship. It's your job to populate the tables.